# Form inputs slide down - height: 0 to auto

Tags: javascript, css, forms, slider

I'm currently working on a simple form and trying to make the inputs slide down from height: 0 to height: auto. The idea is for the default to be someone's email, and the roll down to be "New Email" and "Confirm Email" input sections once a button "Change Email" is clicked on.

I've included my code to make it easier to show what I'm working on. Currently, "Change Email" on click just shows the form, but I want it to slide down instead. Similarly, when the form shows and the user clicks "Cancel", the form will slide back up to height: 0. Please ignore that clicking on "Cancel" doesn't work in the snippet, it currently works in my editor and I'm just looking for some guidance on the sliding back up.

Please provide responses that use JavaScript only and not jQuery.

Please run the code to see what it looks like! The "showing up" part starts with the if statement in the JavaScript.

```js
var changeBtnEmail = document.getElementsByClassName('change-item')[0];

changeBtnEmail.addEventListener('click', function() {

  var profContainer = this.parentElement;
  var changeContainer = profContainer.children[1];
  var currentInput = changeContainer.children[0];
  var changeForm = changeContainer.children[1];

  if (changeForm.style.height == 0) {
    Object.assign(changeForm.style, {
      height: 'auto',
      // overflow: 'hidden'
    });
    currentInput.style.display = 'none';
  }
});

var cancelEmail = document.getElementsByClassName('cancel')[0];
var cancelParent = cancelEmail.parentElement;

cancelEmail.addEventListener('click', function() {
  Object.assign(cancelParent.style, {
    height: '0',
    overflow: 'hidden'
  })
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1240px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #666666;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}
button {
  outline: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2.65rem;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
/* Email, Name, Password Styling */

.profile-main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.prof-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.prof-container h3 {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.45rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.change-container {
  width: 60%;
}
.change-container p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.45rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.change-form {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: height 0.5s linear;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.change-form fieldset:first-of-type,
.change-form fieldset:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 15px 0;
  border-width: 0.6px;
}
.change-form fieldset:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.change-form label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -99;
}
.change-form input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.45rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #645564;
}
.change-form input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 0.6px solid #2d9fee;
}
.change-form fieldset:last-of-type {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 1.45rem;
}
.change-form fieldset:last-of-type button {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 7px;
  color: #666666;
  background: none;
  border: 0.6px solid #c0c0c0;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.change-form fieldset:last-of-type button:last-of-type {
  background: #91c789;
  border-color: #91c789;
}
.change-form fieldset:last-of-type button:first-of-type:hover,
.change-form fieldset:last-of-type button:first-of-type:focus {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  border-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.change-form fieldset:last-of-type button:last-of-type:hover,
.change-form fieldset:last-of-type button:last-of-type:focus {
  background: #64895f;
  border-color: #64895f;
}
.change-form fieldset:last-of-type input {
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
  color: white;
}
.change-item {
  /* this is the change button */
  width: 20%;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 1.45rem;
  color: #2d9fee;
  transition: border 0.4s;
}
.change-item:hover,
.change-item:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Account Type Styling */

.account-type {
  align-items: center;
}
.account-type .change-container {
  display: flex;
}
.account-type button {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 1.45rem;
  color: #666666;
  border: 0.6px solid #c0c0c0;
  background: none;
}
.account-type button:first-of-type {
  background: #91c789;
  border-color: #91c789;
  color: white;
}
.account-type button:first-of-type:hover,
.account-type button:first-of-type:focus {
  background: none;
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
  color: #666666;
}
.change-item.delete {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="profile-main-container">

      <div class="prof-container email">
        <h3>Email</h3>

        <div class="change-container">
          <p>first.last@email.com</p>

          <form class="change-form">
            <fieldset>
              <label for="new-email">New Email</label>
              <input type="email" id="new-email" placeholder="New Email" />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
              <label for="confirm-email">Confirm Email</label>
              <input type="email" id="confirm-email" placeholder="Confirm Email" />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
              <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
              <button>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
              </button>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
          <!-- End change-form -->
        </div>

        <button class="change-item">Change Email</button>

      </div>
      <!-- End prof-container email-->

    </div>
    <!-- End profile-main-container -->
  </div>
  <!-- End wrapper -->
</body>
```

Comment: Just FYI you haven't included a fiddle as your question suggests.

Comment: @A1raa sorry, VERY new at this and couldn't figure out how to include the fiddle. I've added my code, it should be straightforward once it's ran, hope that helps!